# Create Circle In 3-D Axes

Tags: matlab, 3d, geometry, axes

I am newbie in `matlab`.

I want to draw something like below pic in 3-D axes and move it mouse move.

i do not have problem with second part(move objects on mouse move) ,
 i do not know how to create this circle in 3-D axes

[image]

Comment: slm, how are you going to get 3D coordinates by a mouse click? since you will click on a 2D surface, `ginput` gives `[x y]`. Do you want `z` to change by mouse click?

Comment: @Kamtal see this link please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26892489/401403

Comment: See `filled` option in `plot`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar i can not use plot because i want to move the circle on mouse move

Answer (score 0):

```
elevation = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
r = ones(1,100);
azimuth = .75 * pi *ones(1,100);
while 1
  axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10])
  view([20 20 5])
  [newx newy] = ginput(1);
  [x,y,z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,r);
  x = x + newx;
  y = y + newy;
  patch(x,y,z,[1 0 0],'EdgeColor','r');
  axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10])
end
```

You can change the radius by `r` like `r = .5 * ones(1,100);`

[image]

But the coordinates of click doesn't seem to be right.

I think you have solved that problem in your previous question.

**Note**

> Coordinates returned by *ginput* are scaled to the XLim and YLim bounds of the axes you click (data units).
>   The figure *CurrentPoint* property, by contrast, is always returned in figure Units, irrespective of axes Units or limits`

Comment: thanks,but as you can see the shape of your circle is different from my picture

Comment: @Arash, see if it got better. I changed `azimuth` and `view`

Comment: thanks,but now there is a problem that the circles creates just in middle of axes,not anywhere

Comment: @Arash, It's because `ginput` just gives `x,y` and the circles are plotted at `z=0`.